# "Need admin approval" while testing as ASP.NET Web Forms application

Tags: azure-active-directory

we have a website that was developed in C# using ASP.NET Web Forms ans is working well,
the thing is that it works with an internal (of the company) authentication, and that kind of authentication will soon expire,
so I have been asked to develop an Azure AD one, but when testing we receive this error [image: error]
to develop the Azure Authentication, we followed some guides like [1st link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/convert-asp-net-webforms-with-windows-authentication-to-use-aad/)
I know that this issue has been reported many times before but Azure AD is continuously evolving so a guide from the beginning of 2021 for example is hard to apply it at the end of 2022
and thanks in advance
PS: if you need any complementary document that I can provide, just ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

[image]

The error usually occurs if the Admin Consent is not consented to the API Permissions you have granted to the Azure AD Application.

Make sure to **grant the Admin Consent to the API Permissions** like below:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> API Permissions -> Grant Admin Consent*

[image]

You can use the below endpoint and sign in as  **`Global Admin`**   and  **Accept**  the consent on behalf of organization like below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/adminconsent?client_id=ClientID
```

[image]

**Otherwise**, you can allow users to consent to the Application like below:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Enterprise Application -> User Settings -> Go to Consent and permissions*

[image]

Comment: thank you for the reply, however I am not an admin, just a user that consumes the service, but I will mark your reply as a solution in order to maybe help others