# Azure AAD - Cross Tenant access to Blazor App getting denied even when configured to allow access

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, blazor, multi-tenant

I'm getting the following error when trying to log in to my Blazor App that is using Microsoft AAD Authentication. The account I'm using to log in is an organizational account outside my Tenant. The login works when I use my personal `live.com` account.

[image]

```
 A user account from identity provider *** does not exist in the tenant.The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.
```

I have allowed Cross Tenant access to the application using the following settings

[image]

and also allowed External tenant access in the app registration

[image]

Comment: `The login works when I use my personal live.com account` --> could you pls let us know that if your `personal live.com` account existing in your tenant by going to Azure AD -> Users -> searching for the account name ?

Comment: @TinyWang Yes, my account exists in the tenant.

Comment: @Rukmini `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/oauth2/v2.0/`

Comment: Can you try changing the endpoint as https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/ as try as (MultiTenant needs common endpoint)

Comment: @Rukmini This is a Blazor Client Side app, where do i change it ?

Comment: @Rukmini Where do i change it ? I got the value which i'm using by checking the browser.

Comment: Could you please include how you are making use of `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/oauth2/v2.0/` endpoint?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250364/discussion-between-rukmini-and-techno).

Comment: I'm afraid you had to invite `organizational account outside my Tenant` into your tenant as the guest then that account can sign in app. Multi-tenant app doesn't mean I can use my own account to sign in your app. Expect you are using a `partner`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/cross-tenant-access-overview

Comment: @TinyWang I don't think there is a need to invite if the above settings are provided. I managed to fix this issue by changing the endpoint and removing an unwanted token scope. Now, another issue popped up, saying my organisational admin needs to grant consent to access this application

Comment: To resolve the error, grant admin consent to the APi permissions in Azure AD Application like https://i.imgur.com/G6LG8Qh.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

[image]

As you are making using of  `https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/` endpoint the users from other organizations can't access the application.

**To resolve the error**, make sure to use **`common`** endpoint as the application is configured as (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts:

[image]

I used the below endpoint to authorize to the Application:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
```

I tried to sing-in with other organizational account outside my Tenant:

[image]

I am able to successfully login to the Application like below:

[image]

In the **`appsettings.json`** file, update the parameters like below:

```cs
"AzureAd": {  
"Instance" : "https://login.microsoftonline.com/"  
"Domain": "DomainName",  
"ClientId": "ClientID",  
"TenantId": "common" ,  
"callbackpath": "redirecturi"  
}
```

**Note**:

> For  **Single-Tenant**  account type, value should be "**`TenantId`**"
> For  **Multitenant**  account type, value should be "**`organizations`**"
> For  **Multitenant and personal Microsoft accounts** type, value should be "**`common`**"

The error "***Organisational admin needs to grant consent to access this application***" usually occurs if the Admin Consent as not be granted to the Azure AD Application.

To resolve the error, **Grant Admin Consent to the API Permissions** as logging into the Portal as Global Admin like below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks.Admin consent needs to be granted by the organaization admin, not in my application i guess.

Comment: See https://imgur.com/a/9U2oaQH

Comment: Refer this to resolve the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74716026/need-admin-approval-while-testing-as-asp-net-web-forms-application/74716555#74716555

Comment: Changing the Authority is appsettings worked. But my appsettings does not look like this.Are you using a client or server app?

Comment: See https://imgur.com/a/BkBuDrs

Comment: I am using client App, if your `appsettings.json` file worked then no need to update it as above.